# How to catch PyCharm debugger's "Stop Button"?

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pycharm

Quick Question:  What signal/Exception does PyCharm's Stop Button send when debugging a python script?

Background: Several posts document that hitting Ctrl-C doesn't send a Keyboard Interrupt/SIGINT signal to a python script when using PyCharm's Debugger.  Fine.  My question is, what *does* get sent to the Python script when clicking the Debugger's "Stop Button".  I'd like to re-write my code to catch whatever that signal/Exception is.    [I'm using OSX w/PyCharm 4.0.4]

Comment: Why do you think that a breakpoint "sends an interrupt" or "raises an Exception" ?

Comment: See [Stop action does not send SIGINT](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13316) issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you stop the process after debugging it, it sends a `SIGKILL` signal to the interpreter.

> Process finished with exit code 137

Exit codes above 128 mean that it's a 128 + a signal's number (in this case, 9, which is a `SIGKILL`).

You could catch `SIGTERM` using [`signal.signal()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal), but `SIGKILL` can't be caught. There's nothing you can do with it.
Well, you could set up a separate script that would monitor the first one (checking for its PID existance in the running processes, for example) and do something if the given process is terminated.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  What version of PyCharm are you running?  When I run your code using "Run" (or pressing ^R), I do in fact get the KeyboardInterrupt when clicking the "stop process" button.  When I run your code using "Debug" (or pressing ^D), I get don't get the KeyboardInterrupt and see only "Process finished with exit code 137" when clicking the "stop process" button.

Comment: @Dutch I'm very sorry, I _did_ run it using Run (^R). I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was concerned was happening -- a non-catchable signal that I can't (easily) use to trigger the "clean up" part of my code.  Thanks for confirming that.